Using `as const` on an object from a constant
I have a weird encounter with Typescript.
When I do this:
const myObject = { a: 0, b: 1, c: 2 } as const;
and do this:
type myObjectType = typeof myObject[keyof typeof myObject];
myObject will have this type:
type myObject = 0 | 1 | 2
BUT, when myObject's value is from a different file (i.e. constants file):
const someObject = { apple: 1, orange: 2, banana: 3 };
Spread someObject on a new variable:
const myObject = { ...someObject } as const;
and do this:
type myObjectType = typeof myObject[keyof typeof myObject];
myObject, for some reason, will have this type:
type myObject = number
I'm expecting this to have the same type like the first example since I just took the value from a different file but for some reason, it doesn't work that way.
I've been searching for a solution to this but I can't seem to find any. I hope someone can answer this. Thanks in advance.

What is someObject's type?

Please [edit] to provide a [mre] we can look at and test. It kind of sounds like you've got const someObject = {a: 0, b: 1, c: 2}; const myObject = {...someObject} as const;. Is that right? If so, please [edit] to show that.  And if so, unfortunately you cannot get the behavior you want, since the information you want to preserve is already lost. as const only affects the type of the literal it applies to, not the types of everything that makes up the literal.  After const someObject = {a: 0, b: 1, c: 2};, the type of someObject is {a: number, b: number, c: number}; it's too late.

@jcalz that I didn't know. I thought it could work since I'm creating a new variable but I guess it just doesn't behave that way.
Thanks!

You told us that the myObject is {...someObject} as const.
Did you also define someObject to be as const?
const a = {
  a: 0,
  b: 1,
};

const b = {
  ...a
} as const;

type B = typeof b[keyof typeof b]; // number

const a = {
  a: 0,
  b: 1,
} as const;

const b = {
  ...a
} as const;

type B = typeof b[keyof typeof b]; // 0 | 1


Nope, I didn't use as const on someObject. I initially thought it should work because I am spreading someObject on a new variable.
Should someObject be as const as well?

@sudo.jv In my former example, b depends on a and a has type of {a: number; b: number;}. And that's it. Even though b is defined as const, there is no way for b to be in the type that one want. The same goes with your code.
